# Count "double" in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to get the frequency of each element of a double vector, representing degrees of a network, in order to plot the degree distribution. I have tried using count like this:

```
> count(degree)
```

Where degree contains data like the following:

```
> degree
  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32 
  7   6   7   6  30  59 103  39 298  20  39  58  34  40  18  26  11  26 177  21  53  63  67  61  28  13  17  46  45  45  55  19  53
```

But it results in the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("count") : 
  no applicable method for 'count' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need `table` instead of `count` as `count` requires a `data.frame/tibble/data.table` as input.  From `?count`

> x - A data frame, data frame extension (e.g. a tibble), or a lazy data frame (e.g. from dbplyr or dtplyr).

```
table(degree)
```

---

If we need to use `count`, convert the `vector` to a `tibble`

```
library(dplyr)
tibble(degree) %>%
    count(degree)
```

Answer (score 3):

We can also use `tabyl` function from `janitor` package to count the frequencies of a variable in a data frame or a single one. Here I'm citing a character vector from documentation but you can use any kind of data type:

```
library(janitor)

val <- c("hi", "med", "med", "lo")
tabyl(val)

 val n percent
  hi 1    0.25
  lo 1    0.25
 med 2    0.50
```